# Worksite - cleaning history of workspaces

Tags: imanage

Recently my firm acquired the Workiste solution (DMS) v9.3.2. It is connected to Outlook as a plugin.

To the left of Outlook, beneath the Inbox, Outbox, Deleted Items and other folders, there is a browser of this DMS, whose contracted label is FileSite.

Within FileSite there are the Documents in Checkout, Recent Documents and Recent Folders blocks.

Within the latter, there are all the 'workspaces' I've been getting via search.

However, many queries of these folder blocks (named 'workspaces') remain forever in the FileSite browser and therefore in Outlook.

I would like to keep only those 'workspaces' already searched and useful to me, those useful to my day-to-day, and not all those I search just take a peek, only.

The Worksite documentation is crappy on the web, so I did not find any information on how to clear the contents of the block called _Recent Folder (and if this is possible to do)

Answer (score 1):

FileSite allows you to view recently accessed workspaces via the Recent Workspaces node. This is typically configured by you system administrator to show the last 10 or 20 workspaces that you accessed.

There is a corresponding My Workspaces node which will show you a list of workspaces that you are interested in, which may or may not be those same workspaces in your list of Recent Workspaces. To add to that list of My Workspaces simply right click any workspace (the reddish box icon that is the root of each workspace folder structure) and select Add to My Workspaces. Once you've done that a shortcut to that workspace will appear in your list of My Workspaces.

While the underlying workspace name typically won't be editable (usually because a company policy prohibits it) the shortcut is yours and you may rename it if you wish.

Also, in My Workspaces you may find that you want to logically group certain workspaces, perhaps because you're working on a set of related projects or matters. In that case you can right click on My Workspaces and select New..Category. A Category is merely a logical grouping of workspaces that is personal to you.

You can also make use of your My Favorites area to store shortcuts to workspaces and categorise them. The main difference between My Workspaces and My Favorites is that the latter allows you to add shortcuts to individual documents and even folders, not just workspaces.

In my experience, most people seem to find that My Workspaces gives them enough flexibility

Note that the My Workspaces and Recent Workspaces etc nodes are themselves configurable. That means your organization's administrator may have relabelled them, eg to My Matters and Recent Matters if you're a legal team, or My Projects and Recent Projects, etc. Also, you may have been restricted to only view certain nodes in FileSite

Your administrator or tech training team should be able to provide you with some comprehensive FileSite user guides that are produced by iManage in PDF format. Those guides provide much more detail

Comment: In fact, I would like to get rid of unused workspaces previously searched for me.

Comment: @MauroSimoes Do you mean you would like to clear the "Recent Workspaces" node? It is not possible to do this manually in FileSite, however there is a way to do it via some code (e.g. by executing a simple VBA macro). There is also a registry hack you may execute to achieve the same thing. Let me know if you'd like me to edit my answer with either of those approaches